# GridView: How to set the number of rows to display

Tags: c#, gridview, rows

I would like my grid view to display only 3 rows any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: you want only 3 rows to be added or you want to set the size of the grid based on row height

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Enable Paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging.aspx) and set the GridView's [`PageSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) to 3.

[How to: Enable Default Paging in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y71xk4a7.aspx)

If you want to restrict your GridView to show only 3 rows without paging, you need to use a `DataSource` with only 3 records (f.e. via SQL-`TOP`-Clause or `Limit` in MySQL or LINQ's `Take(3)`).

Comment: I'd missed `AllowPaging="true"` and `AllowSorting="true"`` on my GridView. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 8):

If you can limit the records in your query, then that's the best approach.

However, if you can't limit them in the query... here is another approach:

1. Set "`allowpaging=true`" and "`pagesize=X`" (change X to how many rows you want visible).
2. Assign a pagerstyle with a custom CSS class.

   <pagerstyle cssclass="hidden" />
3. Set that custom class to:

   .hidden {
     **visibility: hidden;
     display: none;**
   }

Now, your grid will use the paging logic, but the pager controls are hidden.

It's not the cleanest/most elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

place AllowPaging="True" and PageSize="3" in GridView

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple and ensure your DataSource only provides the three rows of data you need to display.

Failing that, you could set the `.Visible` property of all `Rows` to `false`, except `Rows[0]` through `Rows[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways that i can think of.....

1. Get your dataset from your query.
2. Create columns and add to your gridview...
3. Add 3 rows on a button click and keep the index static
4. On the same click, clear your grid and add next three rows....

OR

Use paging!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

go to view and click on grid and a small overlay opens allowing (requiring you) to enter a number for the column. then preview and click save

Answer (score 0):

you can use Repeater instead as follow.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate>
<table class="center">
    <tr>
```

<%#If((Container.ItemIndex <> 0 AndAlso Container.ItemIndex Mod 4 = 0), " ", String.Empty)%>
        
            ' PostBackUrl='<%# Container.DataItem("url")%>' >

```
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It looks there is a code formatting issue. Please fix it.