# How to split single grid view into multiple grid view

Tags: asp.net

how to split the single grid view into multiple grid view.I have a table it can have a maximum  7 value not more than that.how to split grid view  my values and print int the tables

Comment: If you're talking about Pagination and WebAPI please see (OData)[http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api]

Comment: sorry i want it in asp.net

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227218/gridview-how-to-set-the-number-of-rows-to-display