# How to show N items in a WPF data grid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

For window width I am using:

```
SizeToContent="Width"
```

But for height I am hard coding it by hand. But how can I make it so that the window shows maximum N data grid items?

So if there are more than 20 items, show only 20 of them, if less then show all of them.

Comment: Do you want to have all the items loaded in the grid, so for instance when you sort it you will see the top 20 items, or you want to just have the initial 20 items and work with them?

Comment: Is that a `.Take(20)` question? Or looking for a pager?

Comment: I want all the items loaded because I have about 50-60 max, so it's not a lot. But I want to have my window to resize to show max 20 items in the data grid view (with scrollbar). If it's less than 20, the window should also be resized both at launch and also runtime, so if I remove or add an item in code which I am doing, then the window should apply the same logic above and resize appropriately.

Comment: So it's a matter of resizing my data grid view to show 20 items or less (with scrollbar) and have the window resize based on this. My app only consist of this single data grid view.

Comment: I think this question is very similar to this other one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227218/gridview-how-to-set-the-number-of-rows-to-display

Comment: @SergioAlejandroRiberaCosta: Seems to be but will paging stop updating those items? I want all the items to keep updating.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MaxHeight="400"` on window, with appropriate `MaxHeight` value so that only 20 items are visible in `DataGrid`.

That way all the items will be loaded, scrollbar will be shown if there are more than 20 items, and window will resize properly for any lower number of items. Which is what I think you are trying to achieve based on your comment above.

Of course, this solution will not work if window still needs to be fully resizable manually.

**EDIT**

Since the suggestion above cannot be applied, here is another one...

So, based on all of the information, and in case I couldn't or didn't want to use paging, I would do something like this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window ...     
        Title="MainWindow"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>        
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" />        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    // Total number of items
    private int dataCount = 0;

    ...

    private void AddDataToGrid(SomeData data)
    {
        // Update item counter
        dataCount += 1;
        // Auto size if now there are 20 or less items, otherwise do not change size
        this.SizeToContent = dataCount <= 20 ? SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight : SizeToContent.Width;

        // Update grid data
        this.dataGrid.Items.Add(data);
    }

    private void RemoveDataFromGrid(SomeData data)
    {
        // Update item counter
        dataCount -= 1;
        // Auto size if now there are 20 or less items, otherwise do not change size
        this.SizeToContent = dataCount <= 20 ? SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight : SizeToContent.Width;

        // Update grid data
        this.dataGrid.Items.Remove(data);
    }   
}
```

Basically, I would add methods for adding or removing `DataGrid` items, then check the total number of items every time, and fit the height of the window to the content if needed by setting `SizeToContent` value to `WidthAndHeight` or `Width`.

Comment: Thanks but I can't had code the value. Because I dont know the actual row height. Also when there are less than 20 items, it needs to show only those with the window resized so you need to know the actual row height at run time.

Comment: @JoanVenge If that is the case, I've updated my answer with different possible solution.

Comment: Thanks but this only resizes the window no? I need the data grid to be resized to show only N items.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand, you were writing about window resizing in other comments... Anyway, in the example that I have posted, window will follow the size of the datagrid, until the number of items exceeds 20, in that case window will stay the same size, but scrollbar will appear for datagrid.

Comment: Thanks I will try this but I don't understand how you are using the hard coded height value of 400? Basically I need the data grid to always be at the height of 20 rows, or less, never more than 20. But I need the program to figure out or use the actual displayed row height coz if I am not wrong WPF only knows about this at runtime not compile time. Imagine multiple computers each using different resolution and hidpi settings. I don't want to use different hard coded height values for each instance.

Comment: That hardcoded value is only from first suggestion, in the second one (the one after the edit) there are no hardcoded values.

Comment: Ok is it possible to do this using XAML? Because I am not adding items in code so I have to adapt my code to code above to use your method.